# Calculating the time period for multiple signals in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, periodic-processing

I'm currently doing a fluid simulation. The flow is calculated in discretized steps of 0.0625 s. I think the flow is periodic in all points because it is periodic in some points.

I also calculated the Fourier Transform of this. There was a minor peak at 0.5356 Hz (and some more at higher frequencies). So the period is 1.8671 s. This was consistent with the corresponding signal.

But now I want to prove that this counts for all the nodes of my mesh (around 7000 nodes). Is there a fast way for doing this in MATLAB?

Thanks

(I would have loved to add pictures but I couldn't)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If the input `X`  is a matrix, `Y = fft(X)` returns the Fourier transform of each column of the matrix. This is considerably faster than looping through each column and calling `fft(x)` one at a time.

You will need to reshape your input data into a 2-D matrix, where the row dimension is time, for the analysis.

Comment: But I want to do this for 7000 nodes. Is this realisable in Matlab? And how do i control this? If i plot it all on one plot, it will probably be quite a mess. Isn't there some simple metric to see if the signal is periodic?

Comment: I tried what you said. The answer (srry that i can't post the figure but my reputation is too low) is a frequency spectrum for all the nodes consisting of 6 peaks. The biggest one is at 0Hz, then 5.1Hz , 5.5 Hz and then 0.56Hz. The smallest are at 6.2 Hz and 1 Hz. Can I now be sure that this means my flow is periodic since there are only 6 peaks and the sampled time is bigger than the time period?

Comment: In answer to your first question: I don't know how many time steps you have simulated, but a thousand or so Matlab should handle easily - it looks like you found this out yourself.

Comment: The second question is more difficult to answer. Are you calculating the amplitude (magnitude) of each frequency bin and looking for peaks? Then the peaks are probably real - but you need to be sure your time steps are short enough, and that your simulation is numerically stable, before you can decide if the actual flow is periodically varying.

Comment: You might also try calling `detrend(X, 'constant')` before the FFT. This will subtract the mean of each column which should largely remove the zero frequency peak.

Comment: Detrend makes the peak smaller from 7 to 5, but it doesn't remove it. Does this mean anything?

Comment: It's not really significant, it just means there is a significant amount of variability at the very lowest frequencies - a period comparable to the length of time you have simulated.